# Javascript, variable is null - cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, null, getelementsbytagname

I have some basic JavaScript which I'm working around with. It works fine on my localhost by throws an error when implemented on the web.
I get the following error in the dev tools using firefox or crome.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: beige;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #main li {
                width: 100px;
                padding: 5px 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <ul>
                <li>A list item</li>
                <li>B list item</li>
                <li>C list item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var insert = document.getElementById("main");
            insert.getElementsByTagName("li")[1].style.borderRight = "1px solid blue";
        </script>
    </body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Is that the entire code ? I don't see why it would work on localhost and not served elsewhere. Don't you have a cache problem (empty it) ?

Comment: Should work just fine, unless you've placed the javascript in an external file or in the head, executing it before the #main element is available ?

Comment: It works in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gVvp6/).

Comment: @dystroy yes that is the entire code.

Comment: @adeneo javascript is in the footer as per the above code

Comment: And the HTML is valid, and the ID match etc.

Comment: If it's accessible on the web, you might as well drop us the link here.

Comment: @adeneo yes everything is just copied and pasted in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code looks good. there are no errors. The only possible condition where this can't work is that you may have forgotten to change the original id name which you are using in your project with this demo id i.e  `main`.

It is really hard to say. Check by doing the following

- change variable name i.e  `insert` .
- keep the javascript in script tags like `<script></script>`.
- or there could be some hidden characters.

You are enclosing your `html` tag with caps i.e `HTML`. I suppose this might be the problem.

Comment: I know, thanks for all the input - it's kinda doing my head in. Double checked everything. Cleared cache. The id of main is used in my my project so have based everything around that, so I can just copy and paste straight from my test code.

Comment: I just used the following instead which worked fine. `var insert = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
insert[1].style.borderRight = "1px solid blue";`

Comment: for some reason it didn't like getElementById()